# Scalar multiplication two 2darrays

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have following Problem. 
I have two 2d arrays with the size (4,2)

```
a = [[1 1]
[1 1]
[1 1]
[2 2]] 

b = [[2 3]
[2 2] 
[3 4] 
[1 4]]
```

and i want to do column wise scalar multiplication

```
a * b = [[2, 3] 
[2 2]
[3 4]
[2 8]]
```

Comment: obe is a example. the dimensions are flexible -> (i,j) * (i,j) = (i,j)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
c = np.multiply(a, b)
```

and if you want to avoid `numpy`(not suggested):

```
c = [[i*j for i, j in zip(*v)] for v in zip(a, b)]
```

Also, if you want `numpy`'s efficiency but really, really need a `list` and not a `numpy` array, then convert `c` to a list like so:

```
import numpy as np
c = np.multiply(a, b).tolist()
```

Comment: oh...stupid of me. I tried all but not that... :/ thanks

Answer (score 0):

Please try this. It should solve your query.

```
def func():
    a = [[1,1],[1,1],[1,1],[2,2]]
    b = [[2,3],[2,2],[3,4],[1,4]]
    c = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        c.append([a[i][0]*b[i][0], a[i][1]*b[i][1]])
    print c

func()
```